# Take count of column after merging

Tags: sql

I have merged two dataframes and selected for only those rows when a column contains a specific value. Now, I want to count the number of occurrences the value in the column has after filtering for `beak`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    landbirds.size, landbirds.weight,landbirds.feather, sea_birds.beak
FROM 
    land_birds
INNER JOIN
    sea_birds
ON
    land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour
WHERE beak LIKE '%long%'
GROUP BY feather
COUNT(feather) ASC;
```

However, this does not produce an additional column counting the different feather types i.e. `long`, `medium`, `short`.

How can I effectively count the feather types after merging?

Example data:

```
#landbirds
... colour   size   weight   feather
      W       M      12.2     Long
      Br      M      12.7     Long
      Br      S      15.4     Short
..
```

second table:

```
#seabirds
...  colour   beak     
      W       Long  
      Br      Medium 
      Br      Long    
..
```

Expected output:

```
#results based on data above
feather   featherCount
Long          1
Short         1
```

Comment: I am trying to help you in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ccfa/2) but I need to know the exact expected output and maybe also see some sample data.

Comment: Thanks but why does your query do a JOIN on color? If it needs to JOIN on color, then you need to provide sample data for color in the land_birds table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    feather, COUNT(DISTINCT feather) AS featherCount
FROM 
    land_birds
WHERE 
    colour IN (SELECT colour FROM sea_birds)
GROUP BY 1
```